# Como fazer para que o Combo Box faça uma sugestão do que está na lista quando o usuário começa a digitar

Tags: c#

Estou trazendo uma lista de cadastro do banco de dados para o combo box e gostaria que quando o usuário começa a escrever, o combo box fassa uma sugestão

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para que o combobox te forneça uma sugestão é bem simples, altere as seguintes propriedades do seu combobox:

```
  this.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
  this.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
  this.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
  this.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
```

pronto seu combobox irá se comportar da forma que espera.

Comment: Obrigado Samuel pela dica. Deu certo aqui.